# Проблема с автоматической сменой языка в Intellij-idea (RU/EN/IL)

Tags: intellij-idea, properties

После того как перехожу в intellij-idea из браузера, или любого другого окна, происходит автоматическая смена языка, по умолчанию использую в системе 3 языка RU/EN/IL. В любых других приложениях, программах,... такой проблемы нет.

- intellij-idea 2016.1.4 2
- Windows 10
- Puntoswitcher (никогда не устанавливался)

Ставлю в браузере язык руский, перехожу в идею, ставится иврит, возращаюсь в браузер с ивритом. Ставлю в идее английский язык, иду в браузер, с английским языком, возвращаюсь в идею с ивритом. в любых других вариантах все так же
Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно настроить и в чем заключается проблема?

Comment: а какой язык включается? а не стоит ли puntoswitcher?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman иврит, он последний по списку,  puntoswitcher никогда не было

Comment: По умолчанию язык должен переключится на тот который у тебя был до переключения в браузер т.е. в intellij-idea стоит иврит, в браузере русский при переключении на браузер язык меняется на русский если обратно переключаешься то на иврит сменяется язык. это по умолчанию в винде настройки. Или как у тебя как то по другому?

Comment: @ASYOU Ставлю в браузере язык руский, перехожу в идею, ставится иврит, возращаюсь в браузер с ивритом.
Ставлю в идее английский язык, иду в браузер, с английским языком, возвращаюсь в идею с ивритом.
в любых других вариантах все так же

Comment: думаю копай настройки винды скорее всего может когда то что то изменял и забыл по умолчанию все должно быть ок.

Comment: @ASYOU спасибо, посмотрю, даже и не знаю с чего начать

Comment: @Pavel Bereznichenko настройки винды языковые настройки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему, зашел в панель управления, языковые настройки, дополнительные настройки, и поставил галочку напротив "Позволить выбирать метод ввода для каждого приложения" и все получилось! спасибо всем